# Improve performance of jQuery drag animation

Tags: jquery, animation, css, drag

I recently started a new project, which is a CSS3/jQuery flipbook (click to flip, or click & drag the right page).

See it [live here](http://webkit-os.pixelass.com/flipbooktest/) or [play with the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/PXZwf/)

**THE QUESTION:**

How can I improve the speed when dragging the page?

It seems OK in Chrome and Safari, but it's slower/'steppy' in Firefox and really awful in Opera (tested in latest versions on a Mac OS X Snow Leopard)

**BTW..** I'm still cleaning up the code / I tried removing the rotation but it does not seem to change anything.

I had a few testers that complained about performance on Chrome/mac too (it seems "OK" for me)..

Any help/criticism/hint is appreciated.

Here's the code that moves the page (see the fiddle for the entire code)

```
function startMove() {
    $('#flipwrap.movable').on('mousemove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        thisX = parseFloat((e.pageX - offsetX - 190), 10);
        thisY = parseFloat((e.pageY - offsetY - 270), 10);
        positionX = parseFloat((((thisX - 55) * -1) + 310), 10);
        positionY = parseFloat(((thisY + 100) / 10), 10);
        rotateZ = parseFloat((((positionX - 350) * positionY) / 900).toFixed(2) * -1, 10);

        if ($('.page.flipit').hasClass('movable')) {
            $('.page.flipit').stop(true, true);
            $('.page.removeit').stop(true, true);
            $('.page.flipit').removeClass('css-animation').css({
                width: 116 - thisX / 2.1,
                height: 345 - thisX / 8,
                top: -13 + thisX / 16,
                left: thisX + 155
            });
            $('.page.flipit').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + rotateZ + 'deg)  ').css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + rotateZ + 'deg)  ').css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + rotateZ + 'deg)  ');
            console.log('    pX = ' + positionX + ' pY = ' + positionY + ' rZ = ' + rotateZ + ' tX = ' + thisX + ' tY = ' + thisY);
            $('.page.removeit').css({
                width: 40 + thisX / 1.6
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Got to say that it's fairly clunky for me in Chrome, too (latest version, Win7). Apart from that it looks good, though.

Comment: maybe you can compare this to the original   http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/PXZwf/3/   it uses translate for the positioning.. (the animation on mouseup... etc is totally off in this example).. it's just about the animation smoothness of the curled/dragged part while dragging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mousemove is called dozens/hunderds of times each time you move your mouse, cache your selectors, i.e.

```
$('#flipwrap.movable').on('mousemove', function(e) {}
  var pageFlipIt = $('.page.flipit');
  $('#flipwrap.movable').on('mousemove', function(e) {
     pageFlipIt.doStuff();
  })
})
```

But the biggest problem is that animating box-shadows and border-radii is quite processor intensive. I tried removing all of them in your jsfiddle and it was smooth as butter in Opera, but of course it will take away all the charm of your book implementation.

I'd suggest removing all of them and then add them progressively to see where you can find the tradeoff between eye-candy and speed.

Comment: thx I appreciate your help. i removed the box shadow animations but it's still chinky. the borders aren't really animated they just follow the animation.. i tried using translate and scale which makes everything smoother than butter could ever be. yet I can't use scaleX .. sadly. i will try the variable caching . the border radius can't be removed, because then it would just be another awful flipbook ( there are so many bad jquery css flipbooks... and i do not want to use html5 canvas... oh merry xmas BTW

Comment: the box-shadow seems to be the killer... without-box-shadows but with radius. Yet without CSS animations.. http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/PXZwf/9/   but YES.. this looks really awful without the shadow

Answer (score 0):

Well as @Duopixel  said cache the selectors for a start, and chain them. I'd work on simplifying the maths - there are a lot of steps there. But yes, mousemove fires a lot of events, and you have a lot of maths for each of them. so it's going to be hard.

Here's my quick bash at it, hope it is of some use

```
function startMove() {
    var $memoized_page_flipit = $('.page.flipit')
      , $memoized_page_removeit = $('.page.removeit ')
      , $memoized_page_stop = $memoized_page_flipit.add( $memoized_page_removeit )
      , offsetThisX =  offsetX + 190    //saves an addition at every loop..
      , offsetThisY =  offsetX + 270
      , offsetPosX =  offsetThisX + 55 + 310    //saves two additions at every loop..
      , offsetPosY =  ( offsetThisY + 100 ) / 10; //saves one addtion every loop
      , moving = false

    $('#flipwrap.movable').on('mousemove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //tries not to have too many handlers hogging resources
        if( moving ){
            return;
        }
        moving = true;

        thisX = e.pageX - offsetThisX;  //floats and ints are all Numbers
        thisY = e.pageY - offsetThisY;
        positionX = offsetPosX - e.pageX;   //swapping order to save the * -1
        positionY = e.pageY / 10 - offsetPosY

        //make a string only once
        rotateZ = 'rotate(' + parseFloat((((positionX - 350) * positionY) / 900).toFixed(2) * -1, 10) + 'deg)';

        if ( $memoized_page_flipit.hasClass('movable')) {
            $memoized_page_stop.stop(true, true);
            $memoized_page_flipit
                .removeClass('css-animation')
                .css({
                    width: 116 - thisX / 2.1,
                    height:  345 - ( thisX  >> 3 ),     //bitwise shift division
                    top:  -13 + ( thisX >> 4 ) ,
                    left: thisX + 155
                    , '-webkit-transform' : rotateZ
                    , '-o-transform' : rotateZ
                    , '-moz-transform' : rotateZ
                });
            $memoized_page_removeit.css({
                width: 40 + thisX / 1.6
            });
        }
        moving = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: this looks interesting . can't wait to get back home to give it a try... thx s bunch

Comment: So.. I tried your answer. http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/PXZwf/7/ ... I also removed the CSS-animations of the box-shadow and border-radius, but it still seems really awful in Opera/Firefox. I'd be happy to get some feedback from others too.. differences??? etc...

Comment: Yes, I tried it too and didn't see much difference... as I said, those are best practices, but with so much maths and so many events it really is going to be hard.

Comment: i posted a comment on @Duopixel 's answer... removing the box-shadow makes it a lot smoother.. still playing around.. I'm pretty confident about this.. anyways.. thx for your help so far. BTW this is going to be an opensource jQuery plugin once it's done.